# My code is creating an infinite amount of balls

Tags: actionscript-3

It should only create 5 movieclips, could anyone take a quick look?
My friend is using the same code and its working properly for him.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//Criação das variavéis
var bolas:Array = new Array();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startdd);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdd);

function startdd(e:MouseEvent)
{
    e.target.startDrag();
}

function stopdd(e:MouseEvent)
{
    e.target.stopDrag();
}


for (var i:int = 0; i < 5;i++)
{
    var ball:bolamc = new bolamc();
    ball.x = Math.random() * (stage.stageWidth - ball.width);
    ball.y = Math.random() * (stage.stageHeight - ball.height);
    bolas.push(ball);
    stage.addChild(ball);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `i=5` as your condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reasonable thing that came to my mind is that you might have more KEYFRAMES on the timeline, if you have this code on the first frame, and does not have a `stop();` on it, and there is more keyframes then it will start looping thus it will be an "infinite" loop.

Comment: No, not really. It's only experience. :) By the way, if you ask questions on Stackoverflow or it's sister sites, then you can mark answers as "accepted solution" if it helped you out with your problem. You can even upvote posts if they were constructive, but only solved your problem partially. Help the community, increase your reputation so people later on will more likely to help you in the future. :)

Comment: Very true! This is a form of what I call the "frame 1 bug", which can be quite elusive.